# C# to VB.net delegate sub

Tags: vb.net, delegates

I'm continuing to try to learn VB.net, and I visit here often.

So, I'm back again, with a slightly different question.  I received great help previously, and hope to avail myself again.

I have this CSharp code:

```
public delegate void MyHandler(string DataLine);
foo.Handler = new MyHandler(MySub);
void MySub(string DataLine);
```

(When I hover over "MyHandler", the VS helper says "MyHandler.MyHandler(void (string) target)"

I want to set up the delegate in VB.net, but I can't seem to relate the three items so they all work together:

```
Private Delegate Sub MyHandler(ByRef DataLine as string)
??????  as MyHandler
Private Sub MySub (ByRef DataLine as string)
```

Does the "??????" need to be a Dim {something}, or a Declare {something} or ???  Or is there an error in one of the other two lines?

(Let me know if there is any missing info)

Thanks

Charlie

Answer (score 2):

In VB.Net, you can use [`AddressOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y72ewk2b.aspx) to assign a `Sub` to a `Delegate`:

```
foo.Handler = AddressOf MySub
```

Comment: Thanks, a simple copy-and-paste gives me a syntax error.  I'll dig a little deeper now that I have a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Given this:

```
Private Delegate Sub MyHandler(ByRef DataLine as string)

Private Sub MySub(ByRef DataLine as string)
    ' Do something here
End Sub
```

You can declare and instantiate the delegate, like this:

```
Dim TheHandler As MyHandler
TheHandler = AddressOf MySub
```

Comment: This is, I believe, closer to the concept, but I am confused about the scope/location of "TheHandler = AddressOf MySub". Both of the two "Private..." lines are inside the class but outside any module, so they should be class-wide. Likewise, I've put the "Dim TheHandler..." in the same scope.  The "MyHandler =..." is currently inside the Form_Load function, but I am not sure that is correct.  Won't it be invisible when needed elsewhere?  I'm thinking I need to edit my original question to explain more detail.